# Gmail API: Can I restrict access to allow only sending e-mails?

Tags: gmail-api

There are various ways to programmatically send e-mail through a Gmail account: service account, OAuth2, API key, and even username/password if the "less secure" setting is enabled.

However, all of these methods require providing some kind of password or token that would allow a user to call any Gmail endpoint on the account. I want to allow access to the endpoint *only* for sending an email, not for any other Gmail API functionality such as reading email, changing settings, or listing metadata.

[image]

The level of granulairty for an API key pictured above is not nearly enough, as it just restricts access to all Gmail APIs.

Is it possible to restrict access to specific endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit which APIs your project can use, by appropriately selecting them within the "API Library" section. Additionally, depending on the type of account you use, you can apply more restrictions:

1. **Service account**

   This type of access is meant to be used for server-side applications, in which you/your organisation are the owners of the code and credentials. There is, in fact, no option to limit the scopes that the application can use when authenticating with it.
2. **oAuth2 Client**

   This type of access is created to be granted to users on demand, from client-facing applications. Using this one, you can limit the scopes it can use by going to Google Developers Console, selecting your project, and navigating to OAuth Consent Screen>Scopes for Google APIs. This will apply to **any** oAuth client that is declared within your project. In case you need different oAuth clients with different declared scopes, you can consider creating a new project. *Note: the scopes restriction will only apply after your application has been verified*